# Internal Server Error: java.lang.ClassCastException class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: lsfusion

имею таблицу poses с полями cd (INTEGER) и tit (TEXT)
пытаюсь импортировать, получаю вышеназванную ошибку

```
CLASS Poses 'Позиции';
cd 'Код' = DATA INTEGER (Poses);
tit 'Наименование' = DATA ISTRING[255] (Poses);

importFromDB 'импорт db' () {
    EXTERNAL SQL 'jdbc:postgresql://$1/livetest?user=postgres&password=postgrespw' 
             EXEC 'select cd as CD, tit as TIT from poses' 
             PARAMS 'localhost:55000'
             TO exportFile;
    LOCAL tits = ISTRING[255] (INTEGER );
    LOCAL cds = INTEGER (INTEGER );
    IMPORT FROM exportFile() TO tits=TIT, cds=CD;
    FOR iterate(INTEGER i, 1, 10) DO {
        NEW p = Poses {
            cd(p) <- cds(i);
            tit(p) <- tits(i);
        }
    }
    APPLY;
    MESSAGE 'импорт завершен';
}
```

Comment: А можете прислать стек ошибки? Чтобы было видно, на чём конкретно падает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут у postgres проблема с именами полей. Postgres воспринимает их как case insensitive, если только не взять их в кавычки.

Вы указываете имена полей в импорте в верхнем регистре, но postgres нам их возвращает в нижнем регистре. Поэтому надо писать не так

```
IMPORT FROM exportFile() TO tits='TIT', cds='CD';
```

а так

```
IMPORT FROM exportFile() TO tits='tit', cds='cd';
```

Либо второй вариант - взять в кавычки в запросе:

```
EXTERNAL SQL 'jdbc:postgresql://$1/livetest?user=postgres&password=postgrespw' 
             EXEC 'select cd as "CD", tit as "TIT" from poses' 
             PARAMS 'localhost:55000'
             TO exportFile;
```